# Why "wrong username/password" alert comes up even on the first load of page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login form and when I get to the page, it gives me automatically the alert message. I havn't put the username and password info yet.
Here is the page that does the verification of the login form input, Please see why it is behaving like that?

```
<?
session_start();
include "config.php";

if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]) AND isset($_SESSION['pass_user'])){
    $login_user = $_SESSION["login_user"];
    $pass_user = $_SESSION["pass_user"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adm WHERE login = '$login_user'");
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $pass_db = $linha['pass'];
}

if($cont == 0){
    unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
    unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Name of user dont match.\");
    </script>";

}

if($pass_db != $pass_user){//check pass

    unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
    unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Password dont match.\");
    </script>";

}

}else{

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"User and password dont match.\");
    </script>";

}

?>
```

Comment: It's _really_ bad practice to inform the user which field (username or password) didn't match.  Just tell them that the login failed, nothing more.  Otherwise you're giving them information about your usernames and passwords.

Comment: It is not advised to alert important messages with Javascript( User could have disabled JS). Also page refresh via HTML tags is also not good as compared to PHP `header`. Try to look into displaying errors in `<div>`s on the same page. If `login.php` & `process.php` is different, pass `error=1` in `Get` back to `login.php`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have just misplaced an else:

```
<?
session_start();

include "config.php";

if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]) AND isset($_SESSION['pass_user'])){

    $login_user = $_SESSION["login_user"];
    $pass_user = $_SESSION["pass_user"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adm WHERE login = '$login_user'");
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $pass_db = $linha['pass'];
}

if($cont == 0){

    unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
    unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Name of user dont match.\");
    </script>";

}

if($pass_db != $pass_user){//check pass

    unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
    unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Password dont match.\");
    </script>";

}else{

    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"User and password dont match.\");
    </script>";

}
}
?>
```

However, As mentioned by @David, you should not specify that only password is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the following if statement returns false:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["login_user"]) AND isset($_SESSION['pass_user']))
```

When that happens the following code will be executed:

```
} else {
    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"User and password dont match.\");
    </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove else statement from your code.Now use it.

```
 <?php
session_start();

include "config.php";

if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]) AND isset($_SESSION['pass_user'])){

$login_user = $_SESSION["login_user"];
$pass_user = $_SESSION["pass_user"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adm WHERE login = '$login_user'");
$cont = mysql_num_rows($sql);
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$pass_db = $linha['pass'];
}

if($cont == 0){

unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

echo "
<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
alert(\"Name of user dont match.\");
</script>";

 }

if($pass_db != $pass_user){//check pass

unset($_SESSION["login_user"]);
unset($_SESSION["pass_user"]);

echo "
<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT='0; URL=login.php'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
alert(\"Password dont match.\");
</script>";

}

}

?>
```